# How to setup vscode / chrome debugger with webpack when vue project in sub directory

Tags: vue.js, webpack, command-line-interface

I am coding a CLI project in vue using VS code and trying to get my debugger setup properly, but I can't seem to get the proper overrides setup for webpack. My workspace folder is Project and I have two sub folders api for my server code and client for my vue code. The following launch.json setting seem to stop my code in the correct place, but the little debugger dots jump up 3 lines when I start it up.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "vuejs: chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:8080",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/client/src",
      "breakOnLoad": true,
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "webpack:///./*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "webpack://./src/*": "${webRoot}/*"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am also using vue router if that makes a difference.